# Python skipping if statement even though its True

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create a loop that checks the contents of a list of lists for a name and returns the index of the name if true. When I write the code without the else statement it works but when I add the else statement it skips the if condition and just applies the else condition. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
outer_list = [['Mother', 'Sharon', 'f', 35, '170cm'], ['Father', 'Bruce', 'm', 37, '189cm'], ['Daughter', 'Amelia', 'f', 10, '137cm']]

name = 'Sharon'
index = -1
index_pos = 0

for inner_list in outer_list:
    if name in inner_list:
        index += 1
        index_pos = index
    else:
        index_pos = -1

print(index_pos)
```

Comment: Think about what a `for` loop does and what happens the 2nd loop.  Also look into the `enumerate` function and the `break` keyword.  Using a source debugger or adding some print statements to follow your logic will help.

Comment: Follow your code step by step on https://pythontutor.com/…

Comment: FYI: `index_pos = next((i for i, l in emumerate(outer_list) if name in l), -1)`. Does what you want.

Comment: You should learn how for loop works and iterate it yourself 1 by 1 and you will see the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you should

1. put index += 1 before the if statement
2. initilize index_pos as -1, and drop else statement

Then it should be correct to print or return index_pos

Answer (score -1):

When  you wrote your code without `else`, like this

```
for inner_list in outer_list:
    if name in inner_list:
        index += 1
        index_pos = index
```

The variable `index_pos` is assigned only if it finds a match in any of the sublists. And then on its not modified.

But when you add an `else` case like

```
else:
    index_pos = -1
```

You are resetting your position. Simply think, you found a sublist with a name in it, so you assigned the position and went to next sublist, there you did not find the name, and now the else works - resetting the already found position. This is where it goes wrong.

You can use a `break` statement, if you think you need only the position of the name , that occurs first. Then it will not check further in other sublists for eg.

```
for inner_list in outer_list:
    if name in inner_list:
        index += 1
        index_pos = index
        break; #This ends the search!
```

You don't need the else statement, unless you want to force the check, the name should exist in all lists.